# Orcale - Missing Right Paranthesis

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run an oracle query using, Case when and Sum together, It gives me an error saying I am missing the right paranthesis.

The query below,

```
SELECT  c.Customer_name,
        CASE WHEN SUM(status = 'DELIVERED') = count(*) THEN 'A'
            WHEN SUM(status = 'DELIVERED') > 0  THEN 'B'
            WHEN SUM(status = 'SUBMITTED') > 0  THEN 'C'
             ELSE 'No Match'
        END AS Match
FROM    Customer_Order c
group by c.Customer_name order by c.Customer_name;
```

Changed my query to look like this and it says, I am missing keyword

```
SELECT  c.Customer_name,
        CASE WHEN SUM(c.status) = 'DELIVERED' = (count(c.status)) THEN 'A'
            WHEN SUM(c.status) = 'DELIVERED' > 0  THEN 'B'
            WHEN SUM(c.status) = 'SUBMITTED' > 0  THEN 'C'
             ELSE 'No Match'
        END AS Match
FROM    Customer_Order c
group by c.Customer_name order by c.Customer_name;
```

Comment: You can't have two equals in a comparison: `SUM(c.status) = 'DELIVERED' = (count(c.status))`  Clearly my previous advice didn't help.  If you want to sum thing that equal something and the compare that to something else you will need a subquery.

Comment: Your problem is not a simple syntax error - neither of your attempts really make any sense as SQL. You'll need to explain what you're actually trying to achieve, including a sample schema and data (a [mre]) so that someone can put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what I think you are trying to do includes counting all the cases where `status = 'DELIVERED'` and `status = 'SUBMITTED'` and then comparing those with something to determine what the outcome is.  But you can't sum a conditional expression like `status = 'DELIVERED'` so you need to do it in two steps: one to make a number out of the conditional and one to compare the sum with something.

Step 1:  To count the cases where `status = 'DELIVERED'` you need a column that is 1 when the status is `DELIVERED` and 0 when it is not (and the same with 'SUBMITTED').  That way you have numbers to sum.  So the data we want to run your query on is:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN status = 'SUBMITTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Is_submitted,
  CASE WHEN status = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Is_delivered
FROM Customer_order
```

Step 2: Now we can use your query on the results of Step 1:

```
SELECT
  c.Customer_name,
  CASE WHEN SUM(c.delivered) = count(*) THEN 'A'
       WHEN SUM(c.delivered) > 0 THEN 'B'
       WHEN SUM(c.submitted) > 0 THEN 'C'
       ELSE 'No Match'
  END AS X
FROM (the query above) as c
GROUP BY c.Customer_name
ORDER BY c.Customer_name;
```

Substituting Step 1 into Step 2 we get the actual query:

```
SELECT
  c.Customer_name,
  -- SUM(c.Is_delivered),
  -- SUM(c.Is_submitted),
  -- count(*),
  CASE WHEN SUM(c.delivered) = count(*) THEN 'A'
       WHEN SUM(c.delivered) > 0 THEN 'B'
       WHEN SUM(c.submitted) > 0 THEN 'C'
       ELSE 'No Match'
  END AS X
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN status = 'SUBMITTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS submitted,
    CASE WHEN status = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS delivered
  FROM Customer_order
) as c
GROUP BY c.Customer_name
ORDER BY c.Customer_name;
```

Try it here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mSdREEgU1mT1pvczG2kZgm/1

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to count true comparions; unlike some other languages, in SQL a true value is not the same as 1 and a false value is not 0 so you need to use a `CASE` expression to convert the comparison to something that can be summed (or counted).

In this case, you can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Customer_name,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(status)
       THEN 'A'
       WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'B'
       WHEN COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'SUBMITTED' THEN 1 END) > 0
       THEN 'C'
       ELSE 'No Match'
       END AS Match
FROM   Customer_Order
group by Customer_name
order by Customer_name;
```